# Random style tag appearing in simple php templated site?

Tags: php, html, css

I've mostly, up until now, done work with pure HTML, CSS and JS/JQuery but am now moving over to development a little more - enjoying it loads!

Having an issue with PHP file templating - using a header.php, index.php and footer.php file, my index output renders an extra style tag (that is empty) when I load my file.

Here's the code for the header.php:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
</head>
```

and index.php:

```
<?php require("header.php");?>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <h1>Page header in here</h1>
        <p>Paragraph in here</p>
    </div>
<?php require("footer.php");?>
```

The extra empty style `<style="text/css"></style>` appears just after my final css include (main.css). Bizarre behaviour - what's even more weird  is through the developer tools in chrome it appears and when I view source the standard way it doesn't.

Comment: You can edit the post with the change @ChrisSaganic.

Comment: Aw I'm so confused at how to even use this site, I'm still learning, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, this is Chrome's deal. Please check, if this additional style appears under "sources" tab. Chrome standard source view under developer's tools isn't strict source. f.e. under 'source' tab you can see raw angular. But under elements, angular variables are converted to strings (or something else). For specific answers, you should post your question on chrome forum.

One thing more: If I were You, I would create file like this:

```
  <html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
</head> 
<body>
    <?php require("template1.php");?>
    <?php require("template2.php");?>
</body>
    <!-- some JS inclusions -->
</html>
```

And template files like this:

template1:

```
<p>This is my template 1</p>
```

template2:

```
<b>This is another template</b>
```

So that templates are totally separated and replacable.
Of course this is VEERY simplified example, and you should spend some time thinking about architecture of your next website. Cheers mate!

Comment: It doesn't appear under the sources tab, I didn't actually recognise what this did until now either. Thankyou for the info!

Regarding templating structure, right now I'm only dabbling in includes I've done next to nothing with php, why is this method better?

Thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure :) In my opinion, this set is better, because you have separated templates for separate things. It's not propable, that you will change your header of footer often, but you will change content, for example, between site's subpages. In the main file you can create simple menu containing links. When certain link is chosen, you can check that using $SERVER['URI'], and include proper template. :) This is really good way to learn what routing is, and why it's important. I recommend you to do some codeshool.com tutorials :) cheers!